# Repartitioning a mapwithstateDstream

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I am using a mapwithstate function on another filestream and then doing some actions on that..when I trace my application I see that there are just 2 parttions after my mapwithstate function for mapped1 MapWithStateDStream..I wanted to know if I can repartion this dstream as well..I then run some action job on that so it need to have more partitions to be run correctly

the codes are as follow

```
val join=ssc.textFilestream(..,..)
var mapped1=joined.mapWithState(stateSpec)//.persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY_SER)

//mapped1=mapped1.repartition(100)..this line doesnt work 

mapped1.checkpoint(Duration(batchIntervalSeconds * 1000 * 1))

  mapped1.foreachRDD(_.count())
```

the line mapped1=mapped1.repartition(100) doesn't compile gave me below mismatch error

```
found   : org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream[(SIMPLE_KEY_JOINS, Long)]
[error]  required:    org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.MapWithStateDStream[SIMPLE_KEY_JOINS,String,L   ong,(SIMPLE_KEY_JOINS, Long)]
```

Any help would be appreciated..